# nginx: Dynamically limit requests based on path

Tags: nginx, scalability

We have a service that serves up user-created assets dynamically. So a user can upload a file and share it using a url like `/path/to/asset/unique_id`. We currently use the `limit_conn` module to protect our system by blocking IP addresses that are flooding us with requests.

But we also want to limit requests *based on the request path*. So if we get a spike in traffic for `GET /path/to/asset/unique_id`, we start limiting requests to that path but the rest of our service continues to serve assets normally.

Right now we're modifying our nginx config to deny requests using the "location" directive once we see a huge spike for a specific path. But we want our service to be proactive and automatically limit requests per path just like how the `limit_conn` works for IP addresses.

Does anyone have any idea how to accomplish this? Is it possible?

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: The only thing we've done for this is to specifically deny certain paths using the location directive. For example:     

location /path/to/asset/unique_id {
        deny all;
        return 404;
}

But this does not scale.

Comment: i would try to combine `limit_req` and Lua module

Comment: This may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40586006/nginx-dynamic-rate-limit (and I have nothing more to say)